# Omit iterator in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a more elegant way to write the following piece of Python?

```
[foo() for i in range(10)]
```

I want to accumulate the results of foo() in a list, but I don't need the iterator i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `_`:

```
[foo() for _ in range(10)]
```

This means exactly the same thing, but by convention the use of `_` indicates to the reader that the index isn't actually used for anything.

Presumably `foo()` returns something different every time you call it. If it doesn't, and it returns the same thing each time, then you can:

```
[foo()] * 10
```

to replicate the result of calling `foo()` once, 10 times into a list.

Answer (score 0):

`map` would be nice if foo() took an argument, but it doesn't.  So instead, create a dummy lambda that takes an integer argument, but just calls foo():

```
map(lambda i:foo(), range(10))
```

If you are on Python 3.x, map returns an iterator instead of a list - just construct a list with it:

```
list(map(lambda i:foo(), range(10)))
```

Answer (score -1):

By no means more elegant, but:

```
[x() for x in [foo]*10]
```

I think beyond that you have to go to Ruby ;)

Answer (score -2):

`map(lambda _ : foo(), range(10))`

although this trades your problem with a meaningless iterator i with a new meaningless argument to the lambda expression.